# ReplaceAll giving Replacement Rules Error

Tags: replacement

I'm new to Mathematica and am trying to learn from the Mathematica Cookbook by Sal Mangano. I've been trying to learn about the replace method using the right arrow, but keep running into the below error.

```
x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4 + x^5 /. x \[RightArrow] N[Pi]

ReplaceAll::reps: {x\[RightArrow]3.14159} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

Any idea why this is occurring?

EDIT: This is occurring because of the syntax `\[RightArrow]` instead of `->`. I guess my question then becomes, what is the correct method for the arrow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\[Rule]` instead.

Comment: Or `->` what is "Minus" and "Greater"

Comment: `x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4 + x^5 /. x -> N[Pi]` works for me. If it doesn't for you, you might have a prior definition for `x` that's interfering; try `ClearAll[x]; x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4 + x^5 /. x -> N[Pi]`. Does this help? (If you want `x` to be treated as a local variable without erasing its global definition, try `Block[{x}, x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4 + x^5 /. x -> N[Pi]` or `Module[{x}, <the same>]`)